# WSL+Docker ghost environment

Tags: docker

[reposting a question that was closed as off-topic over on SO]

I'm running docker in wsl, and testing my containers by invoking docker-compose from the linux prompt.

Sometimes my docker-compose call connects to the same docker environment hosted by docker desktop - I can see the set of containers running in the windows app.

Sometimes docker and docker-compose seem to be calling into some ghost environment. A different set of images and volumes are running. Everything runs fine (modulo changes like divergent database contents) but I don't see them running in the Windows docker app.

I haven't been able to root cause the circumstances under which docker connects to one environment over the other- it seems to change only after a reboot.

My question is how I can control or switch between these environments, and why the second environment's assets don't appear in the windows app.

````
$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1```
````